# WIX, does custom action in InstallExecuteSequence, will run on silent mode?

Tags: wix, wixsharp

does `InstallExecuteSequence` run at silent mode?

I basically using wixsharp but wix is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Technically, this is just a Windows Installer (aka: MSI) question. Nothing specific to WiX Toolset about it. :)